# How to plot a 3D heatmap in python

Tags: python

I want to plot a 3D heatmap in python. As an example of data, my information is as follows:

```
x-axis= hop count (2,4,6,8,10)
y-axis= Power values 
[(9.1, 10.9, 9.3, 10.3),(9.1, 11.9, 9.3,8.3), (9.4, 10.9, 9.3, 10.5),(9.9, 10.0, 9.7, 10.7), #for DR=10
(9.1, 10.9, 9.3, 10.3),(9.1, 11.9, 9.3,8.3), (9.4, 10.9, 9.3, 10.5),(9.9, 10.0, 9.7, 10.7),#for DR=20
(9.1, 10.9, 9.3, 10.3),(9.1, 11.9, 9.3,8.3), (9.4, 10.9, 9.3, 10.5),(9.9, 10.0, 9.7, 10.7),#for DR=10
(9.1, 10.9, 9.3, 10.3),(9.1, 11.9, 9.3,8.3), (9.4, 10.9, 9.3, 10.5),(9.9, 10.0, 9.7, 10.7) #for DR=30
 ]
z-axis= Data rate (10, 20, 30, 40)
```

So here, for example, `data rate=10` and `hop count=2` values of power consumption are `(9.1, 10.9, 9.3, 10.3)`. Similarly, `data rate=10` and `hop count=4` values of power consumption are `(9.1, 11.9, 9.3,8.3)` and so on.

I have looked into some example plots but I am confused how can I adjust my multiple values.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you actually want? Have you looked at matplotlib pcolormesh? This is a heatmap library, but i don't understand as your x has shape 5 yet y is 16x4 https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html

Comment: my x-axis has 5 values and y-axis has 4 values. Because I generate power consumption values for each hop count (x-axis) 2,4,6,8,10 with data rate 10,20,30,40. So you can say each hop count is checked for all data rate values.

Comment: @OceanScientist yes I checked link but my problem is I am confused about different data sizes at x,y, z axis.

Comment: I would consider making 4 or 5 separate or subplots, one for each of your x or z. `plt.pcolormesh(y)` will plot your array. But your current y is shape (16,4) so to use pcolormesh you either just use `(y)` or `(x,z,y)`, where x shape is 16 and z is 4. I think plotting a 3d heatmap here will be very uninterpretable, so 4 or 5 plots (one for each x or z) will be much better - if I understand your question properly.